# Python var storing syntax

Tags: python, variables, printing

Can you tell what is the difference between these two types of storing variables because I can see that both works fine when storing and printing. Thanks

```
country = "USA"
name = ("Harry")

print(country + " " + name)
```

Comment: No difference, the parentheses there don't change anything.

Comment: The parentheses are only seen by the parser as it builds an abstract syntax tree (AST). Both `("Harry")` and `"Harry"` produce the same (single-node) AST.

Comment: `two types of storing variables` -- you are not storing variables. Python variable doesn't store anything (it works a bit differently than other langs). A variable in python is a name that just refers to a value...

Answer (score 4):

Nothing. They're the same.

The second just has parentheses around it to define the order of operation. Like in math, things inside of parentheses are evaluated before things outside the parentheses. Since there's nothing outside of the parentheses however, the parentheses aren't required.

```
name = ("Harry")
```

Just evaluates to

```
name = "Harry"
```

Which is the same as the first line.

Another way to think of it is, if you were doing algebra, would there be a difference between the below two lines?:

```
x = 1
x = (1)
```

The parentheses are just used to group like aspects of the equation, and define the order things are evaluated in, just like when doing math.

*If* you added a comma inside the parentheses though:

```
name = ("Harry", )
```

That would cause `name` to become a 1-element tuple, so be careful of commas in the parentheses, as they change the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the parentheses surrounding the definition of the `name` variable, those parentheses are basically doing nothing. They just group whatever is inside so those operations are done first. Since the only operation other than the parentheses is the definition of the string, nothing is actually done.

Python mostly follows the standard `PEMDAS` order of operations (or `BODMAS` or something similar) that you learned in secondary school.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between those two, both are considered as Strings. However parentheses are used to create "Tuples" so it's good not to use them like that, it would be easy to read the program, because generally, people are used to see parentheses as an indication of tuple, so the chances of misunderstanding are pretty high with that.

But to create a tuple, you just add ' , ' to the "( ) " For ex:

```
names =("harry", )
```

For more understanding, look at this:

[image]